# Jhipster password changed FOR NO REASON

Tags: jhipster

Today I booted up Jhipster, try to log in as "admin" "admin" like every single time before, and doesn't work.
I didn't touch any files.
It just decided to change the password for no reason at all.

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: Other than if you're programmed like a moron, not really. Y'know, other than the files changing the password for no reason, but hey.

Comment: well, I dont think if you change a file it will change the password, since passwords go directly to the DB, maybe check if you deleted the user (or was deleted by no reason at all)

Answer (score 1):

If you kept the default password, maybe someone else logged in and played a trick on you...